# Differential equations with time-dependent random variable. How do I write and solve it?

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-process

I need to write and solve a set of differential equations with Mathematica, like below:

```
eqns[numb_] := 
 Table[{Subscript[W, i]'[
     t] == (Subscript[\[Eta], i][t] - \[Mu] - \[Sigma]^2) Subscript[W,
        i][t] + J (1 - Subscript[W, i][t]), 
   Subscript[W, i][0] == 1}, {i, 1, numb}]
```

I expect to find the solutions `Subscript[W,i][t]`. However, I struggle in the first place to write the functions `Subscript[\[Eta], i][t]`properly. In my model `Subscript[\[Eta], i][t]` represents a Gaussian random variable with a given mean m and a given variance `\sigma^2`. So essentially for every single function `Subscript[W,i][t]`, the function `Subscript[\[Eta], i][t]` should have random values that change in time within a Gaussian distribution for example.
This distribution (its mean value and variance) can be in principle different for  different functions `Subscript[W,i][t]`.

How do I do that? Is NDSolve the right tool to solve this set of equations in Mathematica?

Comment: You should use an SDE solver and formulate your equation in the appropriate SDE framework, either Ito or Stratanovich. Also, you should contemplate what kind of solution you expect, as the general solution is a collection of random paths. Or said differently, each continuous function is a solution, with some equation-dependent "probability".